# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string

Tags: discord.js

I was making my music bot on Discord, and this error appeared and I don't know how to fix it.

> Error: (node:4484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Array

Code:

```
module.exports.run = async (bot,message,args) => {
    if(!message.member.voice.channel) return message.reply("entra numa call ae para eu entra")
    if(!args[0]) return message.reply("tu pois o link para eu tocar um batidão ae?")

    let validade = await ytdl.validateURL(args[0])
    if (!validade) return message.reply("poe um link ae que e valido");

    let data = active.get(message.guild.id) || {};
    let info = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0])


    if(!data.conectar) data.conectar = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
    if(!data.fila) data.fila = [];
    data.guildID = message.guild.id;

    data.fila.push({
        songTitle: info.tile,
        requester: message.author.tag,
        url: args[0],
        announceChannel: message.channel.id
    });

    if(!data.dispatcher) play(bot, data);
    else {
        message.channel.send(`Adicionado na fila: ${info.title} | quem pois a música foi o: ${message.author.id}`);
    }

    active.set(message.guild.id, data);
}

async function play(bot, data) {
    bot.channels.cache.get(data.fila[0].announceChannel).send(`está tocando agora: ${data.fila[0].songTitle} | quem colocou a música foi o: ${data.fila[0].requester}`)

    data.dispatcher = await data.conectar.play(ytdl(data.fila))
    data.dispatcher.guildID = data.guildID;

    data.dispatcher.once('end', function() {
        end(bot, this);
    })
}

function end (bot, dispatcher) {
    let fetched = active.get(dispatcher.guildID);

    fetched.fila.shift()

    if(fetched.fila.length > 0) {
        active.get(dispatcher.guildID, fetched);

        play(bot, fetched);
    } else {
        active.delete(dispatcher.guildID);

        let vc = bot.guilds.set(dispatcher.guildID).me.voice.channel;
        if (vc) vc.leave();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `play` function, you provide the entire `data.fila` array to `ytdl`, but you should be providing just the URL of the first object.

```js
data.dispatcher = await data.conectar.play(ytdl(data.fila[0].url))
```